# Read a file with line continuation characters in Python

Tags: python, io, line-breaks, readlines

I'm looking for a nice pythonic way of reading a file, and joining any lines which are logical continuations of the ones above, as indicated by a line continuation character. E.g.

```
Here is a normal line.
This line continues over  \
two lines.
This line continues over\
three \
lines.
```

I've found one solution here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66064-reading-lines-with-continuation-characters, but it seems unwieldy.  There is a nice solution from Daniel Wang  in the comments using a generator:

```
def loglines(rawdata):
    lines = []
    for i in rawdata.splitlines():
        lines.append(i)
        if not i.endswith("\\"):
            yield "".join(lines)
            lines = []
    if len(lines)>0: yield "".join(lines)
```

This works fine, provided you can read the whole file at once. I wondered if there are any built-in functions which handle this, or whether anyone has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
with open("data.txt") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        while line.endswith('\\'):
            line = line[:-1] + next(fin).rstrip('\n')
        print line
        ...
```

You can also pull this out into a generator if you wish

```
def continuation_lines(fin):
    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        while line.endswith('\\'):
            line = line[:-1] + next(fin).rstrip('\n')
        yield line


with open("long.txt") as fin:
    for line in continuation_lines(fin):
        ...
```

Comment: Much nicer, just use `next()` indeed. You could still make this a generator too, like my (now deleted) answer used.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, I provided a generator version

Comment: You may want to re-introduce the newline, but that's just about perfect otherwise (already gave my +1).